# Random casting errors with System.Animation when using WPF desktop app?

Tags: c#, wpf, casting

I have written a LOB WPF desktop application. Recently, I have had a few users complain about errors like these:

> InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression' to type 'System.Windows.Media.Animation.Clock'.
>
> InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression' to type 'System.Windows.DependencyObject'.
>
> InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.DependencyProperty' to type 'System.Windows.Media.Animation.AnimationClock'.

I was able to briefly reproduce the error simply by using the application randomly (without revealing too much about the app - clicking on items in a ListBox which retrieves some data and displays a form that the user can type information into which auto-saves when the user clicks on another item in the list).

My app does NOT make use of any animations. I don't think I have a single `<Storyboard>` or anything else that moves in the app.

I googled around for these errors and nothing really came up regarding System.Animation casting errors like these.

I'm not looking for a *specific* answer regarding my app's code, but more of a general "If you're getting animation casting errors, try X, Y, or Z..."

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset ListBox or other controls style to default to see if fixed, maybe your control are inheriting some general style behavior or bindings.

For example:

```
<ListBox Style="{x:Null}" />
```